# Loop through this structure of array

Tags: php, arrays

How would I get the value of `children` in the below structure of an array?

```
Array
(
    [post_id] => 2773
    [children] => Array
    (
    )
)
```

I tried this, but it didn't work:

```
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    print_r($value['children']);
}
```

It simply returned nothing.

Comment: Your `foreach()` is going 1 level too deep. `children` will be a `$key` so you would need to do `foreach ($array as $key => $value) { if($key == "children") print_r($value); }`

Comment: Add `error_reporting(~0);` at the top of your script and you will know why it's not showing anything.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to do any looping at all. Just do this:

```
print_r($array['children']);
```

Comment: What if `children` contains another array? How would I get that?

Comment: @user3866797 That depends heavily on what that array is, what it's called, etc. However, if you just had another array with the name `children`, you could just do `$array['children']['children']`.

Answer (score 1):

Your example returned nothing because the `children` array is empty.

If your array looked like this (*example*):

```
Array
(
    [post_id] => 2773
    [children] => Array
    (
         [0] => Item,
         [1] => Item,
    )
)
```

Then your `print_r($array['children'])` would return something.

Alternatively, you could do this:

```
foreach($array['children'] as $item) {
    echo $item ."<br />";
}
```

<sup>(*Provided that the array isn't empty*)</sup>

Answer (score -1):

You could use `var_dump($array)` instead and it would give you more detailed information and the inner array.

Comment: Why is this a bad resolution, it is a much faster solution to debugging problems?